# Cassandra Schema Migration for Java in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra

I use [Cassandra Schema Migration library](https://github.com/patka/cassandra-migration) to initialize database whenever run project. By the tutorial :

```
Database database = new Database(cluster, "nameOfMyKeyspace");
MigrationTask migration = new MigrationTask(database, new MigrationRepository());
migration.migrate();
```

Where should I put above script to :
in SpringBootApplication or Cassandra Config or something else?

How to keep and check the version of database? Is there any tutorial for this library?

Answer (score 2):

You can add a CommandLineRunner class which will run at start of application. Something like this :

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class AppStartupRunner implements CommandLineRunner {

@Autowired
Cluster cluster;

@Autowired
private Environment environment;

@Override
public void run(String...args) throws Exception {
    log.info("Starting DB Migration");
    Database database = new Database(cluster, environment.getProperty("cassandra.keyspace"));
    MigrationTask migration = new MigrationTask(database, new MigrationRepository("resources/cassandra/migration"));
    migration.migrate();
    log.info("DB Migration Complete");
}
```

}

Hope this helps.